# Conditional type based on the value of another key

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is there a way to use an interface based on the value of another key?

So, I would like `options` to use a particular interface if `driver` equals a particular value:

- if `driver == 'a'` use `InterfaceA`
- if `driver == 'b'` use `InterfaceB`

I thought something like this might work but it doesn't.

```
export interface InterfaceA {}
export interface InterfaceB {}

export interface MyInterface {
  driver: string
  root: string
  options: driver == 'a' ? InterfaceA : InterfaceB
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few different ways to do this, but I tend to take this approach as it gives me the easiest to read error messages:

```
export interface InterfaceA {}
export interface InterfaceB {}

type MyInterfaceA = {
  driver: 'a',
  root: string,
  options: InterfaceA,
}
type MyInterfaceB = {
  driver: 'b',
  root: string,
  options: InterfaceB,
}
export type MyInterface = MyInterfaceA | MyInterfaceB;
```

As far as I know these have to be a `type` not `interface`, as interfaces don't support union types. (thank you @jcalz).

It's possible to write the above without duplicating the `root` property, which can be useful if there are more common properties, but I end up duplicating everything anyway as error messages are a lot clearer when avoiding nested unions and intersects.

Comment: It may be helpful to point out that this pattern has a name and documentation: [Discriminated unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions).

Comment: `type MyInterfaceA {` is missing `=` btw

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn Thanks, fixed!

Comment: Thanks! Looks like this is working how I would like!

Comment: @Evert: why do you use `type` instead of `interface` for `MyInterfaceA/B`? Is there any advantage?

Comment: @TmTron you simply can't do unions with interfaces.

Comment: @Evert can you please take a look at my [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-hkbbxq) and explain what I am missing?